# Read out File during awk

Tags: awk

My script continuously reads a file with awk and evaluates input data. Now I need to read and write the first line of the output file. There is the information, what in which row is (°C of first sensor, °C of second sensor) etc.

I tried it like this:

```
awk '
{
    System("awk 'if(NR==1){print $0}' \"OutputFile\"" | getline result)
    print result " it worked" #Print First line
}
' "InputFile"
```

Without the System("...") and the backslashes in the string it returned me the right value:

```
awk 'if(NR==1){print $0}' "OutputFile"
```

But it seems, that I make some mistakes inline. What is the right syntax for catching this line? Is there maybe even an easier solution?

Comment: `if(NR==1){print $0}` isn't quoted anymore, so is interpretted by the shell, other than that using system to call awk within awk is ridiculous anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
awk '{ getline result < "OutputFile" ;
     print result " it worked" #Print First line
  } ' "InputFile"
```

there is no need to call system (e.g. a shell) that call a awk within awk.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! Getline, so easy, perfect.

Comment: @Sider, please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and accept this answer if it helped you.